# Swift UICollectionView, last cell adds another cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

So I have a `UICollectionView` that is based off a `numOfPlayers` array. I have it set up so that the maximum number of players is 7. I would like, if possible, for the last cell of the `UICollectionView` to add another cell(or player) to the array. Then if it is the 7 player it just becomes another player.

I would like to reduce the number of buttons needed. Any help or a point in the right direction.

The max that I want in the array is 7. There are check and balances to make sure that it doesn't go over 7. There are checks also just in case I does go over 8.

The array starts out with the min of 3 elements.
So 3 elements showing in the collection view, then a 4th being a cell to add a 4th. Once the 4th is added to the array then the 5th cell be add cell. Repeat. When there are 6 elements in the array, the 7th cell should be add an element. Once the 7th element is added then it should only show 7 cells and only 7.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return apl.numOfPlayers.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "playerCell", for: indexPath) as! APLCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor =  .green
    
    cell.playerLvlLbl.text = "\(apl.numOfPlayers[indexPath.row])"
    
    return cell
}
```

The background color is just a place holder to see the cells. Making sure they are generating the correct way.

Comment: do u want to add one more array like if u had 7 elements in array then u want to add one more element it will be total 8 ..???
is it ..?

Comment: updated the question. Hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: Could you show us your code for the collection view? Would be helpful to know where you're at.

Comment: Code for numberOfItemsInSection and for cellForItemAtIndexPath specifically*

Comment: I am learning UICollectionView. So I basically just have the bare minimum.

Comment: your question is not clear.. @Micheal

Comment: @Sahil Omer, sorry I don't know how much more clear I can be.

Comment: @Micheal how your adding elements .? 
calling API ..??

Comment: Really don't see the relevance. Just assume that everything is done internally. I click the cell, it calls a func that I wrote in the relevant object. It then checks to see if the max has been met. If not then it adds a new element to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(apl.numOfPlayers.count < 7) {
       return apl.numOfPlayers.count + 1 //add one here for your cell that will be used to add a player
    }
    return apl.numOfPlayers.count // you could add more checks here to make sure it doesn't go over 7 but in your post you said you already have checks to make sure numOfPlayers is never more then 7 so probably just send this if the inital if fails
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if(apl.numOfPlayers.count < 7 && indexPath.row == (apl.numOfPlayers.count + 1)) { // first check if the add cell is present and check if the cell this is laying out is the last cell in the list
       //write code here to create a "add cell" something like below
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addCell", for: indexPath) as! AddPlayerCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor =  .red
    
        cell.textLabel.text = "Add a new player"
    
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "playerCell", for: indexPath) as! APLCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor =  .green
    
        cell.playerLvlLbl.text = "\(apl.numOfPlayers[indexPath.row])"
    
        return cell
    }
}
```

then you also should override the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method and make sure you change your logic based on whether or not the selected cell is a player or the cell to add a new player

Comment: So for now I can't fully test everything. But so far visually this is working with one change

This:
if(apl.numOfPlayers.count < 7 && indexPath.row == (apl.numOfPlayers.count + 1))

needs to be 
if(apl.numOfPlayers.count < 7 && indexPath.row == (apl.numOfPlayers.count))

Comment: Ultimately, I think this is a great starting point. I should be good to go from here. I won't forget to update the logic at didSelectItemAtIndexPath. Thank you for the jump start.

Comment: Was able to get the logic worked out. I was expecting it to be more complicated and more time consuming. But AGAIN THANKS. Now I can tackle the next issue. This is a huge step for me. Several other projects I have upcoming will benefit from this. Now I can take this an apply this to my TableViews.